# Unable to create Fragment class in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

```
override fun <I : Any?, O : Any?> prepareCall(
    contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
    callback: ActivityResultCallback<O>
): ActivityResultLauncher<I> {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun <I : Any?, O : Any?> prepareCall(
    contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
    registry: ActivityResultRegistry,
    callback: ActivityResultCallback<O>
): ActivityResultLauncher<I> {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

}

When extent with Fragment it is expect to implement the above overrride method, What needs to return?? When implement compose library in gradle.

Can any one suggest how to set up project for some screen as Composable and some screen as activity and fragment likw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update or add your fragment ktx dependency to the latest version:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0'
```